# Greenfoot play sound if an object of class type is getting closer with a distance to another class object

Tags: java, greenfoot

I am working on a simple car game on greenfoot and I wanna add an alert sound if my car is getting closer to a truck

This was my trial in the truck class's act method but it keeps on showing an exception:

```
if(!getObjectsInRange(60, Car1.class).isEmpty()) 
{
   Greenfoot.playSound("alert.wav");
}
```

please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Which access gives the exception? Post the exact and complete message, and at best separate the parts into lines to find it better. Like: `List<Actor> cars = getObjectsInRange(60, Car1.class); boolean noCars = cars.isEmpty(); if (!noCars) // ...`

Comment: What kind of exception does it give?